# Generate An MD5 Hash of An Image Using HTML5 / JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, hash, md5, filereader

Using the HTML5 File API and any JavaScript crypto library, how can I generate an MD5 hash of the file?

To read the file:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var contents = e.target.result;
  // What goes here?
};

reader.readAsBinaryString(data.files[0]);
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This goes there:

```
var reader = new FileReader();

reader.onload = function(e) {
  var contents = e.target.result;
  // This goes here:
  var hash = CryptoJS.MD5(CryptoJS.enc.Latin1.parse(contents));
};
```

Be sure you include the CryptoJS library:

```
<script src="http://crypto-js.googlecode.com/svn/tags/3.1.2/build/rollups/md5.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks. That gives me a hash, but it is not the correct hash (compared to Ruby, bash and an online JS hasher).

Comment: Are you using `reader.readAsBinaryString` to load in the file?

Comment: Yes I am using `reader.readAsBinaryString(data.files[0]);` (added to my question). I've also tried using `reader.onloadend` for the callback.

Comment: I just did some more research, and found that it may have to do with the string encoding. Try my edited answer, which adds an encoding step.

Comment: CryptoJS.MD5() returns an object, you'll have to call its toString() method to get the MD5 string.

Comment: Confirming it works as of today, compared md5 with the one from `md5` command line tool and it was the same