# How we can find whether image is modified/manipulated using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, node.js, image-processing, detection, image-manipulation

My requirement is user has to upload their invoice copy/image. Based on their purchase details offer needs to be sent.

I need to find whether the image is modified/manipulated. is there any solution available in javascript/node?

Comment: Can you please rewrite your question using correct grammar? I don't understand what you mean

Comment: Store original [image file hash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236114/generate-an-md5-hash-of-an-image-using-html5-javascript) and later compare original and current hashes. At some point int the future we could use [SRI](https://www.w3.org/TR/SRI/) feature for cross-browser check of all resources integrity, but currently it is not implemented for all sub-resources yet.

Comment: Agnius thanks for your reply. My requirement is different, please see my updated question description.

Comment: What would prevent your users from taking a real photograph of their screen displaying an item they don't own? What would prevent them from sending you an original photo someone else did send?

Comment: Thanks for your reply Kaiido, if the receipt does not send already then still we accept. otherwise, I am tracking based on invoice number and date and time of purchase

Answer (score 0):

if you have  `lastModifed` time You can use fs.stats to compare

```
  fs.stat(path, (err, data) => {
    console.log('check if file/folder last modified date, was it after my last check ');

//I use moment module to compare dates
let previousLMM = moment(lastModifed);
let folderLMM = moment(data.mtime.toISOString());
let res = !(folderLMM.isSame(previousLMM, 'second')); //seconds granularity
return callback (null, res);
  });
```

Comment: Thanks for your comment Madz. but, whoever modified the file can also modify the file modification date and all the EXIF data.

Also the file modification /creation date can be reset by e-mailing it or downloading it from the web.