# Using an MD5 hash to validate image files in Cypress

Tags: image, webpack, hash, browserify, cypress

In order to validate the content of images on my site in Cypress, I want to compare the source of an image displayed on my page to the contents of the expected image within my fixtures directory.  My initial thought is to compare an MD5 hash of the image to a known hash for the expected image.

1. How do I capture the raw source of an image on my web page using Cypress?
2. How do I generate an MD5 hash from the raw source of the image file?

Once both of these questions are answered, I can simply assert that the two hashes are the same.  I'd like to avoid using a 3rd party hash library from Node.JS, because it would require that the npm dependency be transpiled into browser-friendly JavaScript using webpack or browserify.  In my experience, this does not always work.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31236114/generate-an-md5-hash-of-an-image-using-html5-javascript shows how to generate a file validation hash using CryptoJS.  If there is no easily accessible code to accomplish this in browser-friendly JS without a 3rd party dependency then I may try using CryptoJS with Cypress via webpack or browserify.

Comment: If you want to use CryptoJS, it's probably best to use it from Node, which means making a [task](https://docs.cypress.io/api/commands/task.html#Syntax). Otherwise, trying to webpack it in to the browser side seems problematic, unless already done as part of the app build.